# R package sqldf sum over multiple columns

Tags: r, sum, typing, sqldf

Suppose I want to do summary using sqldf("select id,group, sum(v1),sum(v2),.....sum(90) from data group by id,group"),

Since I have more than 90 variables, is there a way to do it efficiently than typing 90 times ?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have to use `sqldf`? the `dplyr` package has `summarise_each` which is really handy for situations like this.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! it's not necessary to use sqldf. I am learning R and used to use SQL so wanted to see if equivalent exists in sqldf.

Answer (score 4):

Using the built in `anscombe` data set add `id` and `grp` columns for the sake of the example.  Then create the selection string, `sel`, and insert it into the SQL statement as shown:

```
library(sqldf)
anscombe$id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4)
anscombe$grp <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

nms <- setdiff(names(anscombe), c("id", "grp")) # names except id and grp
sel <- toString(sprintf("sum(%s) '%s'", nms, nms)) # "sum(x1) 'x1', ..."
fn$sqldf("select id, grp, $sel from anscombe group by id, grp")
```

giving:

```
  id grp x1 x2 x3 x4    y1    y2    y3    y4
1  1   1 18 18 18 16 14.99 17.28 14.23 12.34
2  2   1 33 33 33 24 24.72 26.77 27.66 25.02
3  3   2 20 20 20 16 17.20 14.23 14.92 12.29
4  4   2 28 28 28 43 25.60 24.23 25.69 32.86
```

Also note that this is easy to do with base R like this:

```
aggregate(. ~ id + grp, anscombe, sum)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is really helpful! Seems like the aggregate is very straight forward in this case.